# Decoding Honeypot Payload

Tags: hash, honeypot

Apologies for the basic question. I have searched, but I had trouble even determining search terms.

I set up a Cowrie honeypot (SSH/Telnet) last night on a VPS. I find this in the cowrie log today.

```
  "data": "\"\\x16\\x03\\x03\\x00\\xcf\\x01\\x00\\x00\\xcb\\x03\\x03W\\xff\\x82(\\xa9\\x00^QZ\\xa7d\\xd4\\x8d\\xdf*\\xe7O}\\x12D\\x7f\\xb8\\x1eD`/\\x93l#\\xd4\\xb6(\\x00\\x00F\\xc0#\\xc0'\\x00<\\xc0%\\xc0)\\x00g\\x00@\\xc0\\t\\xc0\\x13\\x00/\\xc0\\x04\\xc0\\x0e\\x003\\x002\\xc0+\\xc0/\\x00\\x9c\\xc0-\\xc01\\x00\\x9e\\x00\\xa2\\xc0\\x08\\xc0\\x12\\x00\\n\\xc0\\x03\\xc0\\r\\x00\\x16\\x00\\x13\\xc0\\x07\\xc0\\x11\\x00\\x05\\xc0\\x02\\xc0\\x0c\\x00\\x04\\x00\\xff\\x01\\x00\\x00\\\\\\x00\\n\\x004\\x002\\x00\\x17\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x13\\x00\\x15\\x00\\x06\\x00\\x07\\x00\\t\\x00\\n\\x00\\x18\\x00\\x0b\\x00\\x0c\\x00\\x19\\x00\\r\\x00\\x0e\\x00\\x0f\\x00\\x10\\x00\\x11\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x12\\x00\\x04\\x00\\x05\\x00\\x14\\x00\\x08\\x00\\x16\\x00\\x0b\\x00\\x02\\x01\\x00\\x00\\r\\x00\\x1a\\x00\\x18\\x06\\x03\\x06\\x01\\x05\\x03\\x05\\x01\\x04\\x03\\x04\\x01\\x03\\x03\\x03\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x02\\x01\\x02\\x02\\x01\\x01\"",
```

I tried running this through http://decode.urih.com/ as hex and base64 (without the "data:" "\"). I then tried stripping a single \ from it, then both, then the space too - retrying and not getting anything back each time.

I have  tried searching, but when I find encoding/hash identifiers I'm not sure what format I'm to present it in, all slashes removed?

Can someone please help with the following questions.

- How can you determine format?
- Where do I even begin if I want to see the plaintext version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\x16\x03\x03...
```

This is the begin of a TLS record and it looks like a start of a TLS handshake (i.e. HTTPS or similar). There is no plain text apart from maybe the target hostname if the client uses the TLS SNI extension.